# Remove corporate domain and associated policies from Windows 7 enterprise

Tags: windows-7, administrator, domain

I have a Windows 7 machine currently associated with a corporate domain. I want to remove the domain and use the computer in my home network (the license is my private one but the pc was temporarily used in a corporate network for an assignment). 
I have access to a user associated with the domain that is also member of the administrator group. I do however not remember the password to the *user* called "Administrator".

When going into the settings to remove the domain and instead assign a workgroup, I get a warning such as "make sure you have access to the administrator account". Since I do have access to *a user with administrative rights* but not *the administrator user', I'm worried removing the domain would render the computer useless. Is this the case, or will I be able to login using my domain associated "administrative rights user" also after removing the domain?

I'd rather not resort to having to reinstall Windows. :/

Comment: You can always use a boot tool to reset Windows account passwords that you cannot access. Have you tried that?

Comment: No, I kind of wanted to know the consequences of removing the domain *before* removing it. But good to know there are ways to handle inaccessible accounts, should that happen.